# how do I parameterize mysql login when using .my.cnf

Tags: mysql, shell, parameters, psql, my.cnf

I have the following shell script that relies on $HOME/.my.cnf to supply the password. The two calls to mysql are equivalent, but the second one prompts for a password whereas the first does not.  I am trying to write some shell scripts with the connectivity details parameterized except for password.  I tried using #!/bin/sh. There is no whitespace after any of the parameters. Any suggestions?

```
$ cat processlist-state.sh
#!/bin/bash
export HOSTNAME=mysql-us-east-1-123456789.abcdefghijklm.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
export PORT=3306
export USERNAME=master_user

mysql -h mysql-us-east-1-123456789.abcdefghijklm.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u master_user -e "show processlist"

mysql -h ${HOSTNAME} -p ${PORT} -u ${USERNAME} -e "show processlist"

$ cat $HOME/.my.cnf
[client]
password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

-p in the second call forces the password prompt.

> -p = ask for password
>
> -P = connection port
>
> -p{PASSWORD} = use {PASSWORD} from commandline as password